# Wait on Event due to database update

Tags: php, mysql, c

i am using a MYSQL database as form of IPC datastore between web client and C code process on Debian linux. When web client writes some data to the mysql database via php script, i need my C code app to go and pickup that data.

However i don't want the C app continually polling some flag to check if data is available. Is there anyway it a thread can wait on some event from a mysql database or something that when signalled will allow it to unblock and process the data

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a little cumbersome, but it can work.

All you need to make it work is to use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that will fire when data is inserted in the database.

The `trigger` will call a [user-defined function (UDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html) that in turn will signal your `C` code to start processing the newly inserted data.

You don't even need to write your own `UDF`. You can use [sys_exec](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php#sys_exec) from the [lib_mysqludf_sys](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php) library to execute an external program.

Answer (score 0):

please provide whole scenario . What I guess is that you can use EVENTS in combination with a table (for flags ) to achieve  this kind of functionality. I am working on similar problem. If you could provided a detail description it might be helpful. In my case I have trigger which set a flag on  certain records in same table to update , and enables event scheduler , then an event  updates flagged records and disables event scheduler .